# Why isn't the weak anthropic principle trivially true?

Tags: anthropic-principle

The notion that our universe must have properties that mean it can create and sustain humans is necessarily true, given that we are indeed here.

This doesn't address the question of "why" the universe is so, but neither does any other physical theory - it just deals with the characteristics of the universe we observe - which is usually good enough, yet I still see gripes about the anthropic principle.

It might not be satisfying or explanatory - but I fail to see how it could be false.

To clarify - I can understand why physicists might resist the idea of selection pressures on a multi-verse or any number of other extensions of this idea, I'm only referring to the weakest form of this principle.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are correct: it's trivially true that we humans exist and can make observations, so it's trivial to deduce that the universe allows us to do that.

However, this statement is even weaker than what's normally called 'the weak anthropic principle'. I don't think anyone claims your 'super-weak' statement is false. Only the 'properly-weak' one is actually subject of debate.

From Wikipedia:

> The weak anthropic principle (WAP), such as the one defined by Brandon
> Carter, states that **the universe's ostensible fine tuning is the
> result of selection bias (specifically survivorship bias)**. Most often
> such arguments draw upon some notion of the multiverse for there to be
> a statistical population of universes to select from. However, a
> single vast universe is sufficient for most forms of the WAP that do
> not specifically deal with fine tuning.

As you can see, this statement is stronger than yours.